# How does Ameritrade determine the amount of a reorganization fee for a reverse stock split (BIOC) & how does the fee affect income taxes?

Tags: united-states, stocks, income-tax, stock-split

How does Ameritrade determine the amount of the Mandatory Reorganization Fee for a reverse stock split by BIOC?  I read a previous comment where the stockholder was charged $20 by Ameritrade several years back. How does it affect income taxes?

Ameritrade just took my account for a $38 reorganization fee for a reverse stock split.  Somewhere I saw a comment that the stockholder has to receive advanced notice for the fee to be charged.

It is probably hidden somewhere but, while I knew BIOC was doing a reverse stock split, I don't recall seeing any Prior notice of the amount of the reorganization fee or even that a reorganization fee was going to be charged.

This is probably a Live & Learn experience but I would like to see a breakdown of how the $38 fee was calculated & justified.  Is Ameritrade the only brokerage that charges a fee for reverse stock splits or do others charge also & are all of their fees in line with each other?

Comment: A quick google brings up Ameritrade's [commissions and fees page](https://www.tdameritrade.com/pricing/brokerage-fees.page) where they list $38 as the fee for a Mandatory Reorganization, so no advance notification necessary.  It's justified by its mere presence in their menu of charges.

Comment: E*Trade [charges $38](https://us.etrade.com/what-we-offer/pricing-and-rates) for a reorganization, Schwab [charges $39](https://www.schwab.com/legal/schwab-pricing-guide-for-individual-investors). Free at Fidelity.  Another nonuniform fee I've encountered is covered call assignment, which is free or normal commission at some brokers but is $30 at others.

Comment: I also got charged $38 for Mandatory Reorg fee by AmeriTrade for an IPO that I never own any shares from. I called & email them & the dude told me that I owned 20 shares of OCTO (now TYDE) that I purchased on Nov 19th, 2021. I knew the dude was lying coz I would not buy any IPO during Fridays coz I only sell options during Mondays. I also look at all my statements from AmeriTrade, ang screenshots all statements from ThinkOrSwim, I can't find any transactions for OCTO buy or sell records. Worst, they charged all of my 3 accounts, total of $114.

Comment: The fee is a cost of investing, so I would guess it  could be added to your basis price and thus subtracted from your profits when you sell... but I'm not sure how that would show up on the brokerage's statements.